# Вёрстка. Как прижать блок к нижнему блоку?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как прижать блок (к примеру правый блок с меню) к нижнему блоку?

на примере сайта #Хэшкод
как есть
[image]
как хотелось бы
[image]

Comment: css зафиксировать...

Comment: как??? хотелось бы пример кода

Answer (score 3):

Внешний блок (родитель):

```
#outer {
  position: relative; /* или fixed, или absolute */
}
```

Внутренний блок:

```
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

При позиционировании вложенного элемента *absolute*...

- ...если у родителя значение **position** установлено как *static* или родителя нет, то отсчет координат ведется от края окна браузера.
- ...если у родителя значение **position** задано как *fixed*, *relative* или *absolute*, то отсчет координат ведется от края родительского элемента.

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Persio/GtwwZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Правильно, не некроссбраузерно будет так:

```css
.container { border: 1px black solid; padding: 10px; }
.container .block { display: inline-block; vertical-align: bottom; border: 1px black solid; }
.container .left { width: 60%; margin: 0 5% 0 0; height: 500px; }
.container .right { width: 33%; height: 300px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="block left">
        
    </div>
    <div class="block right">
      
    </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Только ло*и делают не кроссбраузерно.

Comment: @Asen, не обобщайте. Бывают задачи под конкретные браузеры.

Comment: ооооочеень редко, @Khvorostin. Да и так делают только недалекие...

Comment: Asen, если вы верстаете кроссбраузерно, вы используете хаки. Если вы верстаете кроссбраузерно, вы не используете CSS3. Если вы верстаете кроссбраузерно, вы используете в пять раз больше времени на тестирование. Всё это ведёт к увеличению времени на вёрстку минимум в 1.5 раза, если макеты не очень сложные. Соответственно, увеличивается и ценник. Также увеличивается сложность проекта, время на корректировки. А если макеты сложные? А если нельзя использовать JS? А что будет, если вы тыкнете на iOS по лейблу? А как это исправить?

Comment: Получается, что это лохи и недалёкие ищут компромисс между сложностью, стоимостью и кроссбраузерностью. Только лохи оценивают изменение конверсии от недостаточного даунгрейда для старых браузеров. Только лохи (ну и недалёкие) сначала спросят, какова планируемая аудитория, чтобы решать, верстать кроссбраузерно или нет. Только лохи забьют на то, что у 10% пользователей проекта уголки будут не скругленными и сделают их в одну строчку за минуту, а не будут полдня резать макеты и наводить кошмар в вёрстке.

Comment: @Asen, стоит все-таки учесть корпоративные веб-решения, заточенные под конкретные задачи. В данном случае вполне возможно ограничиться одним браузером и не думать об остальных. 

Это редко, да. Но редкость компенсируется ценником.

Comment: что-то вы расфлудились по пустяку:)
так всё-таки 1-ый или 2-ой вариант кроссбраузерный???

Answer (score 0):

вот так можно. с jquery. тока не заморочился с css width. написал руками. можно самому находить. а так вот чуть переделанный пример:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#inner").css("left",$(document).width()-50);    
});
```

```css
#outer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #ccc;
}
#inner {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f00;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='inner'>
  </div>
</div>
```

или даже вытащить блок в отдельный div:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#inner").css("left",$(document).width()-50);    
});
```

```css
#outer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #ccc;
}
#inner {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f00;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='outer'>
    <pre>
    З
    д
    е
    с
    ь
    
    б
    у
    д
    е
    т
    
    о
    ч
    е
    н
    ь
    
    м
    н
    о
    г
    о
    
    т
    е
    к
    с
    т
    а  

    З
    д
    е
    с
    ь
    
    б
    у
    д
    е
    т
    
    о
    ч
    е
    н
    ь
    
    м
    н
    о
    г
    о
    
    т
    е
    к
    с
    т
    а      
    </pre>
</div>
<div id='inner'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вот так легко и просто это делается.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.block {
  display: block;
}
.left {
  background: red;
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
}
.right {
  background: green;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="block left">
        
    </div>
    <div class="block right">
      
    </div>        
</div>
```